# How to build an object from similar key value prefix in a map

Tags: java, list, properties, split, maps

Firstly I am using Java to write this.
So I have a Map with keys and values like this.

```
 Key  = Value
"a.1" = "a1"
"a.2" = "a2"
"a.3" = "a3"
"b.1" = "b1"
"b.2" = "b2"
"b.3" = "b3"
"c.1" = "c1"
"c.2" = "c2"
"c.3" = "c3"
```

What I need to do is get it to split all up and make so that eventually I can loop through and create new objects using

```
someloop{
    new someObject(a1,b1,c1); // new someObject(a2,b2,c2);  // new someObject(a3,b3,c3);
}
```

I need to be able to make it dynamic so I can add another prefix (d,e) and also check if a number is missing or is skipped.

Comment: "while also stay in order." Ooops. Do you know that "a.1", "a.2" and "a.10", will be ordered as "a.1", "a.10", "a.20" if you use string (i.e. lexicographic order)?

Comment: I guess keeping it in order isn't really that important.

Comment: If you don't, how do you plan to detect holes?

Comment: Are prefixes always one US ASCII letter (a through z)? Are there always exactly three key-value pairs for each prefix? Or does `SomeObject()` accept varargs?

Comment: Can you explain the splitting part? Create an object of all values ending with the same number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the constructor of SomeObject to accept a list of Strings, this might work:

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("a.1", "a1");
    map.put("a.2", "a2");
    map.put("a.3", "a3");
    map.put("b.1", "b1");
    map.put("b.2", "b2");
    map.put("b.3", "b3");
    map.put("c.1", "c1");
    map.put("c.2", "c2");
    map.put("c.3", "c3");

    Map<String, List<String>> grouped = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    entry -> entry.getKey().split("\\.")[0],
                    HashMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

    List<SomeObject> objects = grouped.values().stream().map(SomeObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(objects);
```

Comment: Or if your `SomeObject()` constructor is varargs only, it will still accept an array: `List<SomeObject> objects = grouped.values().stream().map(list -> list.toArray(new String[list.size()])).map(SomeObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());`.

Answer (score 1):

I have omitted input validation:

```
public static void buildObjects(Map<String, String> keyValuePairs) {
    List<List<String>> sortedValues = new ArrayList<>();
    // assuming keys are ending in a digit 1 through 9, add empty lists to sortedValues to hold values
    sortedValues.add(null); // index 0
    for (int index = 0; index <= 9; index++) {
        sortedValues.add(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : keyValuePairs.entrySet()) {
        String key = pair.getKey();
        int indexOfDot = key.indexOf('.');
        int suffix = Integer.parseInt(key.substring(indexOfDot + 1));
        sortedValues.get(suffix).add(pair.getValue());
    }
    for (List<String> list : sortedValues) {
        if (list != null && ! list.isEmpty()) {
            new SomeObject(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
        }
    }
}
```

You will probably also want to add code that does something with the created objects.

If you want to be sure about the order of values passed to the constructor, you may use a `new TreeMap(keyValuePairs)` or even `new TreeMap(yourComparator).putAll(keyValuePairs)`. This will control the order in which the keys are processed.